# Realm swift beginGroup/endGroup equivalent

Tags: ios, swift, realm

What is the equivalent of beginGroup/endGroup (kotlin) in swift? I need to rebuild this query below in swift. I have read the [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm-legacy/docs/swift/latest/index.html), but I couldn't recreate such query.

```
fragment.realm.where(Item::class.java)
  .`in`("type", Item.Type.values().map { it.name }.toTypedArray()) 
  .apply {
      isEmpty("section")
      or()
      beginGroup()
      // Do something
      endGroup()
  }
  .sort("sortScore", Sort.DESCENDING)
  .findAll()
```

Comment: Why do you need the `beginGroup` and `endGroup` there? They don't seem to be necessary, as they are after a `or`.

Comment: Yeah - the code is pretty vague; what's it do? What's the purpose of the group? Can you provide an example of your data (your Realm model) and tell us what you're trying to query for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning of `beginGroup` and `endGroup` are just "parentheses", so that you can group the sub-expressions in your query. In Realm Swift, you can either write queries in Swift syntax after version 10.19 (because of the [`Query`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm-sdks/swift/latest/Structs/Query.html) struct that supports dynamic member lookup and operator overloading), or using `NSPredicate` syntax. Both of these syntaxes supports using parentheses to group expressions directly, so you can just write something like this:

```
// version 10.19+
let items = realm.objects(Item.self).where { item in
    item.type.in(ItemType.allCases.map(\.rawValue)) &&
    item.section == "" ||
    ( // this parenthesis is what beginGroup translates to
        /* do something */
    ) // this parenthesis is what endGroup translates to
}.sorted(by: \.sortScore, ascending: false)
```

That said, as far as I can see, this pair of parentheses is unnecessary. Anything you put in "do something" will have higher or the same precedence as `||` anyway, so the predicate will have the same result whether or not you put the parentheses.

Side note: the documentation you found is a legacy version of Realm Swift. [This](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/examples/filter-data/) is the new documentation.